My django application is not rendering instead it is just showing the csrf middleware token id in the address bar
This is the base.html file,
<h1>Task Manager</h1>

This is the views.py file section,
class filterTask(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'filter-task.html');

    def output(request):
        
        form = Taskform
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = Taskform(request.GET.get('priorityChoice'))
            ans = Task.objects.filter(priority = form).values()
             

        return redirect(request, 'output.html',context={'ans':ans})



This is the filter-task.html file
{% include 'base.html' %}

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Go To Homepage</a>
<body>
    <h3>Filter Task by Priority</h3>
    <form method="get" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label id="priorityChoice">Enter the priority </label>:
        <select id="priorityChoice" name="priorityChoice" required>
            <option value="low">low</option>
           <option value="mid">mid</option>
           <option value="high">high</option><br>
           
           </select><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


    </form>
    
    

</body>
</html>`

I am trying to filter a specific attribute of an object from the html file by getting the answer from a dropdown option.

Please add your base.html.

base.html is added now

Too many errors.  The CSRF token appears because you are using a GET request, which doesn't require the CSRF token.  GET requests put the variables in the address bar.  If you just want to display the filtered ans, you don't need a form for that.  In the filterTask(View), you can do def get, but I don't think def output is valid.  Your {% include 'base.html' %} shouldn't be in the body of your HTML.

It worked I just renamed from def output to def get and it worked thanks for the help
